# IPython-Parallel: ipcluster and ipcontroller-client.json not found

Tags: parallel-processing, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I'm trying to follow [these](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) instructions on using `ipyparallel` in order to speed up some Python scripts in Jupyter Notebook. When doing

```py
import ipyparallel as ipp
IPPC = ipp.Client()
```

I get the following error:

```
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg

Waiting for connection file: ~/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bf8e572b63bc> in <module>()
     18 display(HTML("<style>.container {width:100% !important;}</style>"))
     19 
---> 20 IPPC = ipp.Client()
     21 
     22 

/home/guest/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipyparallel/client/client.py in __init__(self, url_file, profile, profile_dir, ipython_dir, context, debug, sshserver, sshkey, password, paramiko, timeout, cluster_id, **extra_args)
    415                         no_file_msg,
    416                     ])
--> 417                     raise IOError(msg)
    418         if url_file is None:
    419             raise IOError(no_file_msg)

OSError: Connection file '~/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json' not found.
You have attempted to connect to an IPython Cluster but no Controller could be found.
Please double-check your configuration and ensure that a cluster is running.
```

The file `~/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json` does not exist (folder is *empty*!!) and doing `sudo find / -name ipcontroller-client` doesn't return any results.

Furthermore, when trying to start `ipcluster` in the terminal, I get

```
user@laptop:~$ ipcluster start -n 2
ipcluster: command not found
```

and the "Clusters" tab in Jupyter Notebook is empty: [***Screenshot***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvEr4.png)

However, `ipyparallel` is definitely installed:

```
user@laptop:~$ pip3 install ipyparallel
Requirement already satisfied: ipyparallel in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (6.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (5.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (17.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (4.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (5.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipyparallel) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipython>=4->ipyparallel) (4.6.0)
```

and there are three file `ipcluster`, `ipcontroller`, and `ipengine` in `/home/user/.local/bin` which are Python scripts.

...what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you didn't enable the clusters extension?

After installing `ipyparallel` you need to enable the notebook extension to be able to start clusters from the Jupyter notebook

```
ipcluster nbextension enable
```

You might need to re-install `ipyparallel` before:

```
pip uninstall notebook ipyparallel
pip install notebook ipyparallel
ipcluster nbextension enable
```

(the ipyparallel extension can also be enabled from the notebook's nbextensions_configurator if there's one installed)

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `ipcluster nbextension enable --user`
Otherwise, I got the error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/etc/jupyter'`